# Search name from an array using a text present inside the name

Tags: powershell

I am not pro in PowerShell,

Context: I have a array of database name and I want to search on the basis of part of a string and assign it to a variable.

For example:

```
$databaseList = ("master","test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb","test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb_VIII","test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb_IX","test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb-RBAK")
```

databaseList contain all the database name and has a common string in all name i.e. `test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb`

I want to assign on my following search pattern to various variable like db1,db2,db3,db4

DB Name has only `test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb` (search pattern) need to assign `db1`

DB Name has `_VIII` in the last of `test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb` need to assign `db2`

DB Name has `_IX` in the last of `test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb` need to assign `db3`

DB Name has `-RBAK` in the last of `test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb` need to assign `db4`

Comment: What does "need to assign" mean? What do you want to _do_ when you've identified the correct `db` for a specific database name?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have rectified my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating 4 different variables `$db1` .. `$db4`, I think it would make more sense to create a Hashtable where you can store the database name under a key name.

Something like

```
$databaseList = "master","test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb","test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb_VIII",
                "test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb_IX","test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb-RBAK"

$dbHash = [ordered]@{}
$count  = 1
$databaseList | Where-Object { $_ -match '^test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb' } | ForEach-Object {
    $dbHash[('db{0}' -f $count++)] = $_
}
```

Variable $dbHash now contains:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
db1                            test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb
db2                            test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb_VIII
db3                            test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb_IX
db4                            test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb-RBAK
```

To use one of these items, simply refer to it as `$dbHash['db3']` to return `test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb_IX` etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a question about general program flow rather than powershell, I think. Anyway, here's some code that works. You should think about what happens when the conditions you're expecting aren't met, though.

```
$databaseList = ("master","test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb","test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb_VIII","test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb_IX","test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb-RBAK")

function get_db($dbListItem) {
    if (!($dbListItem.StartsWith("test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb"))) {
        return $dbListItem # Or do some error handling.
    }

    if ($dbListItem -eq "test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb") {
        return "db1"
    }
    elseif ($dbListItem.EndsWith("_VIII")) {
        return "db2"
    }
    elseif ($dbListItem.EndsWith("_IX")) {
        return "db3"
    }
    elseif ($dbListItem.EndsWith("_RBAK")) {
        return "db4"
    }
    else {
        return $dbListItem # Or do some error handling.
    }
}
```

Output:

```
get_db("master")                                          # master
get_db("test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb")                     # db1
get_db("test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb_VIII")                # db2
get_db("unsupported-prefix_VIII")                         # unsupported-prefix_VIII
get_db("test-awe-nfr-lcl-data-sqldb_unsupported-postfix") # same thing comes out
```

Comment: $dbListItem I guess this should be $databaseList ?

Comment: No, that's just the parameter for the method `get_db()`. For example, if you do `get_db("master")`, then inside the function, `$dbListItem` is set to "master". So, you can call change it to anything you like.